# How to read from a file that is actively written to from another program?

Tags: python, io

I'm writing a little something that parses a log file for me.

Currently, I have it open the file and read it continuously in this sort of way

```
file = open(r"log.txt", "rt")
file.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)

while True:
  new = file.readline()
  // do a bunch of stuff with the contents
  await asyncio.sleep(1)
file.close()
```

I do this to sort of mimic the `tail -f` of Linux. Though what I find is that when the server that writes to the log restarts, I guess because the file is still open by Python, it is unable to write to it anymore.

Would a better approach be to open the file, read the contents to the EOF and store in a buffer and close the file, then do my parsing with the data in the buffer, then re-open the file, read in more data and repeat?

Would I have to somehow keep track of where I left off in the file so that I could open it up in the last place I left off?

The log file grows until the server resets. When the server resets, it takes the contents of the file, writes it to a new file (archive) and then re-opens the previous log file truncated (ie fresh).

Could I:

- Open the file
- Read the contents into a buffer
- Then `tell()` to save that last position
- Close the file
- Do my parsing
- Open the file again
- Use `seek()` with the value from `tell()` to read from any new data in the file?
- Close the file

Comment: You could use a `with open` statement, as to only keep the file open whilst actively being used.

Comment: Thanks @lpd11 that works for me! 

`with open('log.txt', 'rt') as file:`